# Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown issue

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

Background: I use an Ideapad330S with Ryzen. 
I have used Ubuntu for almost a year and this problems is new.

When I type `shutdown` or `poweroff` commands on the terminal it seems to run the normal process until the screen turn off. However the power button on my laptop as well as the fan are still on (And never stop). I am able to completely turn off my laptop only if I hit the power off button.

I haven't faced this problem until now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the output of 'inxi -SMCG' and 'tail /var/log/apt/history.log'

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with 3400G and ubuntu 18.04. new problem start from this week. 
Only `sudo reboot -f` can reboot successfully

Comment: Welcome! This answer seems more suitable as a comment and less of a solution for the question asked, as it does not sort the problem itself nor explains what might be the cause for it, and still marks the question as answered. You might want to refer to this link for future questions: [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been filled as [#1880041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1880041). This is a recent regression.

Please pass by and tick "it affects me too" so it gets more attention.